# For $p$ prime, and $T = (0, 2, 4, ... ,2p-2)$, a sub-ring in $\mathbb{Z}_{2p}$. Does $T$ have an identity element? Are there any zero divisors in $T$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $p$ be an odd prime number, and $T = (0, 2, 4, ... ,2p-2)$, a sub-ring in $\mathbb{Z}_{2p}$. Does $T$ have an identity element? Are there any zero divisors in $T$?

I'm really struggling with this and would really appreciate it if someone could help.

Comment: An identity would have to be idempotent: a solution of $e^2=e$.

Comment: ...so $(2p-2)^2=(2p-2)$?

Comment: $(2p-2)^2-(2p-2)=4p^2-10p+6$ which isn't  usually divisible by $2p$.

Comment: So in this case, there is no identity element? And how to check the 0 divisors in T?

Comment: All my argument shows is that $2p-2$ is not an identity in $T$ (except perhaps if $p=3$).

Comment: I'd really appreciate it if you could explain a little more as to how I can exhaustively check whether or not there is an identity element in $T$. I'm still a little confused.

Comment: I suggest looking at a particular example in detail, say $p=5$. If need be, check each element of $\{0,2,4,6,8\}$ modulo $10$ to see whether it is an identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the element is $p+1$.

$$2k(p+1) \equiv 2pk + 2k \equiv 2k \pmod{2p}$$

The zeros divisors are $2k$ and $p$, $k = 0,\dots,p-1$ because $2kp \equiv 0 \pmod{2p}$.